# A nested function in MIPS

Tags: function, assembly, nested, mips

My code has two parts; the first part is making a function that takes in two numbers and return their products. I believe I did this part right.
The second part is where I'm not sure what's the problem is. In this part I need to make a function that find the factorial number, and within this function, I have to use the multiplication function which I made in the first part. Please have a look at my code and tell me what am I doing wrong.

```
.data
Fa_message: .asciiz "\nFAIL TEST\n"
Pa_message: .asciiz "\nPASS TEST\n"

number1: .word 4
number2: .word 5
KnownAnswers: .word 20 
START: .word  16  

.text

main:
# taking in the numbers for  calculation.   
lw $a0, number1 # $a0 =4
lw $a1, number2 # $a1 =5
lw $t0, KnownAnswers # $t0 =20

jal func_multiply # calling the mulyiply function

move    $t4,$v0      # store the product for any further comparisons    
bne     $t0, $t4, FailT  # did it fail the test?
beq     $t0, $t4, PassT  # did it pass the test?

func_multiply: # the mulyiply function
mul $v0, $a0, $a1 # $v0 = number1 * number2
jr  $ra

FailT: # print  "\nFAIL TEST\n"
li $v0,4
la $a0, Fa_message
syscall 

PassT: # print  "\nPASS TEST\n"
li $v0,4
la $a0, Pa_message
syscall   

###---------------------(PART-2)-------------------

lw $a0, number1 # load the number for the factorial procedure
beq  $a0, $zero, factorialDone # (if the number = 0), !0 = 1
mul $a1, $a1, $zero # initializing $a1
mul $a2, $a1, $zero  # initializing $a2
addi $a1, $a0, -1  #  $a1 = (the entered number - 1) 
addi $a2, $a0, 0  # $a2 = the entered number
jal findfactorial
###

#Stop
li $v0, 10
syscall


  findfactorial:


  jal func_multiply # calling the mulyiply function # mul $v0, $a0, $a1 # $v0 = number1 * number2
  move $t4,$v0      # store the product in t4 for any further usage 
  addi $a0, $a0, -1 #  $a1 = $a1-1
  addi $a1, $a0, -1
  bne  $a1, $zero, findfactorial # enter a loop if $a1 does not equal 0



  jr $ra

  factorialDone:
  addi $v0, $v0, 1
  syscall
```

Answer (score 0):

The `jal` instruction modifies the `$ra` register. So if function A calls a function B, then A has to save and restore the value that `$ra` had when entering A so that it can return to the correct place. This is typically done using the stack as temporary storage.

You can push a register on the stack (save it) like this:

```
addi $sp, $sp, -4
sw $ra, ($sp)
```

And pop a register off the stack (restore it) like this:

```
lw $ra, ($sp)
addi $sp, $sp, 4
```

---

Then there's your `findfactorial` loop. You're discarding the result of all the previous iterations, so your result will always be 1*2 == 2. The loop ought to look something like this:

```
findfactorial:
    jal func_multiply 
    move $a0,$v0
    addi $a1, $a1, -1
    bne  $a1, $zero, findfactorial
```

This way you first multiply 4 by 3, then 12 by 2, etc.

---

There are some other isues in your code. For example, if you jump to `FailT` you don't immediately exit the program after printing the message - you just keep executing the code after `PassT`.

Also I'm not sure what this is supposed to do:

```
factorialDone:
addi $v0, $v0, 1
syscall
```

If you wanted to execute syscall 1 (`print_int`), then this is incorrect because it doesn't set up `$v0` properly (it should be `li $v0,1`). And if you wanted this to print the result of your factorial computation then that's not going to happen, because you have a `jr $ra` right before that, so the only time you end up at `factorialDone` is if `number1` contained 0. Also, you'd have to set up `$a0` with the value you want to print.